# Conda not using versions as expected

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda

I think I'm misunderstanding how some of this works so if someone could help that would be wonderful. I created another environment called tf2 with tensorflow 2.1.0, but when I look at the tensorflow version in a jupiter notebook, it shows the wrong version. Here is some debugging I've done:

when I `pip freeze` the tf2 environment I see

```
tensorflow==2.1.0
```

as expected

When I start the environment and run `print(tensorflow.__version__)` I see:

```
2.1.0
```

But when I start a jupyter notebook and `print(tensorflow.__version__)` I see:

```
1.14.0
```

When I check the environment in the jupyter notebook I see:

```
# conda environments:
#
base                     /opt/conda
test                     /opt/conda/envs/test
tf2                   *  /opt/conda/envs/tf2
```

So why is it showing tensorflow 1.14.0?

If it's relevant, I looked at my jupyter and confirmed that it is using the one for tf2:

```
(tf2) [root@conhost con]# which jupyter
/opt/conda/envs/tf2/bin/jupyter
```

I'm wondering if part of this problem is that when I typed `which tensorflow` it couldn't find the library:

```
(tf2) [root@conhost con]# which tensorflow
/usr/bin/which: no tensorflow in (/opt/conda/envs/tf2/bin:/opt/conda/condabin:/opt/conda/bin:/opt/conda/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin)
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

I created the environment from a .yml file that like this:

```
name: tf2
channels:
  - anaconda
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  _ ...
  - jupyter=1.0.0=py_2
  - jupyter_client=6.1.1=py_0
  - jupyter_console=6.1.0=py_1
  - jupyter_core=4.6.3=py37hc8dfbb8_1
  _ ...
  - tensorboard=2.1.0=py3_0
  - tensorflow=2.1.0=gpu_py37h7a4bb67_0
  - tensorflow-base=2.1.0=gpu_py37h6c5654b_0
  - tensorflow-estimator=2.1.0=pyhd54b08b_0
  - tensorflow-gpu=2.1.0=h0d30ee6_0
  _ ...
  - pip:
    - pyqt5-sip==4.19.18
    - pyqtwebengine==5.12.1
prefix: /opt/conda/envs/tf2
```

I would think that changing the environment would update my path, but my path looks like:

```
(test) [root@con ~]# echo $PATH
/opt/conda/envs/test/bin:/opt/conda/condabin:/opt/conda/bin:/opt/conda/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Here's the result of conda list:

```
(test) [root@conhost ~]# conda list
# packages in environment at /opt/conda/envs/test:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                      1_llvm    conda-forge
_tflow_select             2.1.0                       gpu    anaconda
absl-py                   0.9.0            py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
astor                     0.7.1                      py_0    conda-forge
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
bleach                    3.1.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
blinker                   1.4                        py_1    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.15.0            h516909a_1001    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2019.11.28           hecc5488_0    conda-forge
cachetools                3.1.1                      py_0    anaconda
certifi                   2019.11.28       py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
cffi                      1.14.0           py37hd463f26_0    conda-forge
chardet                   3.0.4           py37hc8dfbb8_1006    conda-forge
click                     7.1.1              pyh8c360ce_0    conda-forge
cryptography              2.8              py37hb09aad4_2    conda-forge
cudatoolkit               10.1.243             h6bb024c_0    anaconda
cudnn                     7.6.5                cuda10.1_0    anaconda
cupti                     10.1.168                      0    anaconda
dbus                      1.13.6               he372182_0    conda-forge
decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.3             py37hc8dfbb8_1001    conda-forge
expat                     2.2.9                he1b5a44_2    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.13.1            h86ecdb6_1001    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.1               he06d7ca_0    conda-forge
gast                      0.2.2                      py_0    conda-forge
gettext                   0.19.8.1          hc5be6a0_1002    conda-forge
glib                      2.58.3          py37he00f558_1003    conda-forge
google-auth               1.11.2                     py_0    anaconda
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.1                      py_2    anaconda
google-pasta              0.2.0              pyh8c360ce_0    conda-forge
grpcio                    1.27.2           py37hf8bcb03_0    anaconda
gst-plugins-base          1.14.5               h0935bb2_2    conda-forge
gstreamer                 1.14.5               h36ae1b5_2    conda-forge
h5py                      2.10.0          nompi_py37h513d04c_102    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.5          nompi_h3c11f04_1104    conda-forge
icu                       64.2                 he1b5a44_1    conda-forge
idna                      2.9                        py_1    anaconda
importlib-metadata        1.5.2            py37hc8dfbb8_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        1.5.2                         0    conda-forge
ipykernel                 5.2.0            py37h43977f1_0    conda-forge
ipython                   7.13.0           py37hc8dfbb8_2    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
ipywidgets                7.5.1                      py_0    conda-forge
jedi                      0.16.0           py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
jinja2                    2.11.1                     py_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9c                h14c3975_1001    conda-forge
jsonschema                3.2.0            py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
jupyter                   1.0.0                      py_2    conda-forge
jupyter_client            6.1.1                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyter_console           6.1.0                      py_1    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.6.3            py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_1    conda-forge
keras-preprocessing       1.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.34                 h53a641e_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.8.0               16_openblas    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.8.0               16_openblas    conda-forge
libclang                  9.0.1           default_hde54327_0    conda-forge
libffi                    3.2.1             he1b5a44_1007    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 9.2.0                h24d8f2e_2    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            7.3.0                hdf63c60_5    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.15              h516909a_1006    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.8.0               16_openblas    conda-forge
libllvm9                  9.0.1                hc9558a2_0    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.9                h5ec1e0e_0    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               hed695b0_1    conda-forge
libprotobuf               3.11.4               h8b12597_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.17               h516909a_0    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              9.2.0                hdf63c60_2    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.32.1            h14c3975_1000    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.13              h14c3975_1002    conda-forge
libxkbcommon              0.10.0               he1b5a44_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.10               hee79883_0    conda-forge
llvm-openmp               9.0.1                hc9558a2_2    conda-forge
markdown                  3.2.1                      py_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                1.1.1            py37h8f50634_1    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.4           py37h516909a_1000    conda-forge
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
nbformat                  5.0.4                      py_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.1               hf484d3e_1002    conda-forge
notebook                  6.0.3                    py37_0    conda-forge
nspr                      4.25                 he1b5a44_0    conda-forge
nss                       3.47                 he751ad9_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.18.1           py37h8960a57_1    conda-forge
oauthlib                  3.0.1                      py_0    anaconda
openssl                   1.1.1e               h516909a_0    conda-forge
opt_einsum                3.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pandoc                    2.9.2                         0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.4.2                      py_1    conda-forge
parso                     0.6.2                      py_0    conda-forge
pcre                      8.44                 he1b5a44_0    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.8.0            py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5           py37hc8dfbb8_1001    conda-forge
pip                       20.0.2                     py_2    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.7.1                      py_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.4                      py_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            3.0.4                         0    conda-forge
protobuf                  3.11.4           py37he1b5a44_0    conda-forge
pthread-stubs             0.4               h14c3975_1001    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.6.0                   py_1001    conda-forge
pyasn1                    0.4.8                      py_0    anaconda
pyasn1-modules            0.2.7                      py_0    anaconda
pycparser                 2.20                       py_0    anaconda
pygments                  2.6.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pyjwt                     1.7.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                     py_1    conda-forge
pyqt                      5.12.3           py37hcca6a23_1    conda-forge
pyqt5-sip                 4.19.18                  pypi_0    pypi
pyqtwebengine             5.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pyrsistent                0.16.0           py37h8f50634_0    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1            py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
python                    3.7.6           h8356626_5_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.7                     1_cp37m    conda-forge
pyzmq                     19.0.0           py37hac76be4_1    conda-forge
qt                        5.12.5               hd8c4c69_1    conda-forge
qtconsole                 4.7.2              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
qtpy                      1.9.0                      py_0    conda-forge
readline                  8.0                  hf8c457e_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.23.0             pyh8c360ce_2    conda-forge
requests-oauthlib         1.2.0                      py_0    anaconda
rsa                       4.0                        py_0    anaconda
scipy                     1.4.1            py37h921218d_0    conda-forge
send2trash                1.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
setuptools                46.1.3           py37hc8dfbb8_0    conda-forge
six                       1.14.0                     py_1    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.30.1               hcee41ef_0    conda-forge
tensorboard               2.1.0                     py3_0    anaconda
tensorflow                2.1.0           gpu_py37h7a4bb67_0    anaconda
tensorflow-base           2.1.0           gpu_py37h6c5654b_0    anaconda
tensorflow-estimator      2.1.0              pyhd54b08b_0    anaconda
tensorflow-gpu            2.1.0                h0d30ee6_0    anaconda
termcolor                 1.1.0                      py_2    conda-forge
terminado                 0.8.3            py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.10               hed695b0_0    conda-forge
tornado                   6.0.4            py37h8f50634_1    conda-forge
traitlets                 4.3.3            py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.25.7           py37hc8dfbb8_1    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.1.9              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
werkzeug                  1.0.0                      py_0    anaconda
wheel                     0.34.2                     py_1    conda-forge
widgetsnbextension        3.5.1                    py37_0    conda-forge
wrapt                     1.12.1           py37h8f50634_1    conda-forge
xorg-libxau               1.0.9                h14c3975_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                h516909a_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.4             h516909a_1002    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.2                he1b5a44_2    conda-forge
zipp                      3.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h516909a_1006    conda-forge
(test) [root@conhost ~]#
```

Comment: How did you create the environment and install the package(s)?

Comment: I'll edit the question to answer this

Comment: Where does the environment.yml file come from? Have you tried specifying only the versions of the most important packages?

Comment: I do that but then it adds a bunch of other packages, so then I `conda env export` and use that as my environment file. It's much faster to build after I do that (because it doesn't do the same searching I assume)

Comment: It should be quite fast if you specify the versions of a few packages, how much time does it take?

Comment: Also, are you using strict channel priority?

Comment: Well, I'm not really time-constrained so I can try that. I mentioned that it's faster that doesn't actually matter to me

Comment: I'm not using strict channel priority, but I can try that if you think that's the problem. I don't see why that would be, but willing to try

Comment: There's no need to try, it should be possible to tell if it might be an issue by looking at the output of `conda list`.

Comment: I added the results of `conda list`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210405/discussion-between-jss367-and-amc).

Comment: part of the problem is that I need to add my kernel to make it available for jupyter: `python -m ipykernel install --user --name=tf2`

Comment: I'm not used to dealing with kernels, you run that inside the environment, right?

Comment: Yep. I think that was most of the problem.